# <s:select> use map as list excluding given keys

Tags: java, forms, select, dictionary, struts2

How can I use a map as the list of a struts2 select tag such that I can exclude some values from showing up in the drop down list, based either on the keys I give or the values I tell it to exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choices are slim. It sounds like you just need to manipulate the DOM on the client side. The best way to accomplish this would be to use something like jQuery to manipulate your options. If you need to do this dynamically with no page refresh, I can't think of any other options offhand.

If you need to base your related selects dynamically and with some struts action-interaction, a jQuery/Ajax solution could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove those values from the map before you pass the map to your view.

Comment: That is not an option. I have three dropdowns on the view, if one value is chosen in the firs, I dont want it to show up in second and third dropdown and so on. And I want them to change dynamically

Comment: @locconfused Well, you can do that in two ways. 1) Submit your form with the dropdown's onChange event and populate the other two dropdowns on the server with maps from which you remove the value that was selected in the first dropdown. 2) Do the filtering client-side using Javascript. Just add an onChange event to each dropdown. When a value is selected, remove that value from the other two dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is nothing but DOM manipulation ,better you use java script frameworks to do this . **onchange** of select box is the event to be handled.